# Напишите декоратор, который оборачивает функцию в блок try-except и выводит ошибку, если произошла ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, декоратор

```
def decorator_try_except(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"Found 1 error during execution of your function: {type(error).__name__} no such key as '{error.args[0]}'")
    return wrapper


@decorator_try_except
def some_function_with_risky_operation(data):
    print(data['key'])


some_function_with_risky_operation({'foo': 'bar'})
```

Вывод функции должен быть:

```
Found 1 error during execution of your function: KeyError no such key as 'foo'
```

Вместо этого выводит:

```
Found 1 error during execution of your function: KeyError no such key as 'key'
```

Comment: Текст ошибки должен быть такой Found 1 error during execution of your function: KeyError no such key as 'foo'

Comment: почему же должен быть `foo` в выводе, если вы пытаетесь получить данные по ключу `'key'` ?

Comment: Ну и ключ `'foo'` у вас есть в словаре, почему вы считаете, что должно писать, что его нет?

Comment: Такое задание было

Comment: Write a decorator that wraps a function in a try-except block and print an error if error has happened

    Example
    ```    @catch_errors
    def some_function_with_risky_operation(data):
        print(data['key'])
{list(args.keys())[0]}

    some_function_with_risky_operation({'foo': 'bar'})
    > Found 1 error during execution of your function: KeyError no such key as 'foo'

    some_function_with_risky_operation({'key': 'bar'})
    > bar
    ```

Comment: Спасибо, возможно задание некорректное

Comment: добавьте задание в вопрос, в комментарияй этот код невозможно читать

Answer (score -1):

```
@decorator_try_except
def some_function_with_risky_operation(data):
    return data.get('key', None)


result = some_function_with_risky_operation({'foo': 'bar'})
if result is not None:
    print(result)
else:
    print("Key not found")
```

Comment: Текст ошибки должен быть такой
Found 1 error during execution of your function: KeyError no such key as 'foo'